# Dead Space takes a long time to load

Tags: dead-space

I just downloaded Dead Space from steam (a game I have played through many times - on PC and PS3).  This is the first time I have played it from steam, and it is on my gaming laptop.

The game is taking a very long time to load when I open doors, use the turbo lift, and load the game.  I am running the game from a Vertex 4 SSD and the laptop has a 3.7GHz i7, 32 GB of RAM, and a GTX 470... The game run just fine and the only time it slows down is when it loads.

Is there some way, a setting or something, that I can change to make the game load faster.

Comment: I doubt its a virus thing. Like 5pike said, check for updates. Ask on the Steam community if anyone had the same issues as you have. Your computer is above fine for the game. So it has to be within the game and Steam. If it was a general computer thing, you would know since it would affect other software besides DS.

Comment: You have got enough RAM to put the entire game in system memory. If there is a delay when you load an area you already have visited during a session, that should throw off suspicion from the SSD, since the data should not need to page back to the hard drive. Unrelated but similar; Running Duke Nukem Forever in windowed mode reduced loading speeds to a tenth of Full screen loading times. Sometimes it's up to how the game is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Although it pertains a different kind of loading length issue, try [turning off VSYNC](http://steamcommunity.com/app/17470/discussions/0/864945179800367798/). Other than that, I can't really say myself. Some people say it's the game with the absolutely fastest load times from 2008. Some people complain about minute-long loading times. Either way, like 5pike suggested, checking for driver updates is a panacea for fixing any kind of slowness (whether it be loading, stuttering or lag) in computers, most of the time.

Answer (score -8):

Sadly no.

What you can try is search your laptop for viruses with an application and do the deep check one it individually scans every file and if you have a virus take it to the geek squad for an easy fix.

If you have no viruses it could be the amount of data it's loading is difficult for it so try and delete what your positive you don't need .

The last hope would be to back up you files and wipe all other data from the laptop called the factory reset in the settings and if all that doesn't work it's because the laptop is simply old.

Comment: Sorry but that's just about the only ways don't dislike because you didn't want to hear that

Comment: The "check for virus" is a good tip, but I highly doubt it's a virus thing. OP's laptop seems to be quite capable of running this game, so I think the problem is within the game itself (or steam). My suggestion - Do the usual: Check for driver updates, make an [integrity check in steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335), reinstall the game ... A complete wipe of your laptop should be the last resort.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about steam because sometimes steam carries some pretty bad viruses

Comment: What? Since when does steam carry viruses?

Comment: About 2 months ago there was an emergency update done to steam and some people have been getting viruses like crazy since then

Comment: I see, but viruses usually cause other problems. This would be a very peculiar virus - only effecting the door loading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9351/discussion-between-deathdealer-and-5pike)

Comment: I'm really OCD about what I do on my laptop.  And since Dead Space loading is the only thing that seems to take longer than it should I don't think a virus is the problem.  (I do run virus scans a couple times a week, too).